Why entropy change of a system calculated using reversible heat absorption by system, and why not irreversible heat absorption?
Why entropy change of system is calculated as
$ \Delta S = \frac{q_{reversible}}{T} $
and not
$ \Delta S = \frac{q_{irreversible}}{T} $
Intuitive explaination needed

See Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena, Chapter 11, Homework problem 11.D.1,  They show that, in an irreversible process, in addition to entropy entering the system by heat flow, there is entropy generated within the system due to viscous dissipation and internal heat conduction at finite rates.

Your first equation comes from the fundamental closed-system relation $dU=T\,dS+\sum X_i\,dY_i$, with energy $U$, temperature $T$, entropy $S$, generalized forces $X_i$, and generalized displacements $Y_i$. That is, we can add energy to a system through heat transfer and/or work.
For a system undergoing only pressure–volume work, this simplifies to $dU=T\,dS-P\,dV$.
If we further posit that the volume and temperature are constant, so that $dU=T\,dS$ and $\Delta U=T\Delta S$, then $\Delta U$ can be replaced with reversible heating $q_\text{reversible}$, as the work is zero—leaving only heating—and there are no temperature gradients that would allow irreversibility. (Entropy is irreversibly generated whenever energy moves down a gradient in an intensive property such as temperature or pressure.) Looking at it another way, irreversible heating down a temperature gradient would preclude assigning a single well-defined temperature $T$ in your second equation, rendering it invalid.
Edit: The answer by hyportnex prompts thought—as usual—and a possibly relevant example. Consider two systems at $T_1$ and $T_2>T_1$, connected by a link with a temperature gradient between the two. Allow conductive heating by system 2 of system 1 as they do work or have work done to them such that their temperatures remain constant.   One could write $\Delta S=\frac{q}{T_i}$ for either system $i$ at its constant temperature. Should one append "reversible" or "irreversible" to $q$?  Each system undergoes reversible heat transfer. The total process is irreversible, as hotter system 2 loses less entropy than colder system 1 gains. The total entropy has increased via spontaneous heat transfer down the temperature gradient in the link (whose entropy remains constant because its state doesn't change).

Will it be right to say? that in reversible process all the heat generated by doing the process is completely stored in the system in form of entropy while  in irreversible process some of it is lost in surrounding and hence it underestimates the calculation of heat transfer using entropy change in the system?

Heat cannot be stored, and heat (i.e., energy in transit as driven by a temperature difference) is fundamentally different from entropy, although heat transfer involves entropy transfer. Entropy is also generated by any irreversible process, whether it involves heating or not. Your comments indicate that you're applying the debunked theory of caloric, which I don't think was the intended intention of the other answer.

Sharma"... in reversible process all the heat generated ..." there is no entropy generated in a reversible process. In a reversible process entropy may be moving from one place to another but is not "generated". Instead it can be stored and/or moved and it is always stored/moved at some temperature that may vary with location. You are free to call their product $TS$ anything you wish. Modern textbooks, and most participants in this forum, do not like to use the English word "heat" for the stored "TS" and their preference is to reserve the word "heat" for the product when it is "transported".

It is actually can be either in the right sense. What we intuitively call "heat" is really entropy at a certain temperature. What entropy does not have but the modern view of heat does is that the latter is conserved in a pure thermal linear conduction, but in every other sense entropy is what we would associate with a thermal phenomenon responsible of a thermal process. Even what a calorimeter measures is up to us whether we interpret/calibrate its result as "heat" or as "entropy".
It does not matter whether the "communicated heat" is through a reversible or the "evolved heat" through an irreversible process, this "heat" is the product of the absolute temperature with the entropy that is being transported or generated. It is an unfortunate accident of history that we use the term "heat" for the product itself and not for a factor in the product that we now call "entropy". This historical accident is the cause of enormous confusion and source of your question. It is like considering gravitational energy, $E$, to be the basic concept and define gravitational mass, $m$, as the ratio where $m=\frac{E}{\phi}$ of energy with the potential (height) $\phi =gh$.
